# Restoring MySQL dump ERROR 1449

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, linux, mysqldump, mysql-5.6

I took hot backup (dump) from my Master MySQL DB with below command

> mysqldump -uroot -p --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction --flush-logs --hex-blob --master-data=2 -A  > ~/dump.sql

Master Version: MySQL-server-5.5.41-1.el6.x86_64

At the time of restoration on slave we are getting this error, have I done something wrong.

> [root@Slave ~]$ mysql -u root -p < dump.sql
>   Enter password:
>   ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 150536: The user specified as a definer ('lipl_ga_app'@'%') does not exist

Slave Version: mysql-community-server-5.6.28-2.el6.x86_64

The DB is huge and we don't want to start the restoration process again.

@ Nawaz Sohail I have taken backup of mysql user from below command

> mysqldump -u root -p mysql user > user_table_dump.sql

Restored

> mysql -u root -p mysql < user_table_dump.sql

Comment: it seems backup is restored till line 150536  so split file by lines with patcch of 150536 and then delete the first file and the re combine all files back to one file to avoid restoring full file. Now to resolve the issue simple fix could be make user on the target database with same privileges on source or try restoring all users from source database to target first and then try restoring backup. Do use flush privileges after restoring mysql database to target instance..Hope it helps

Comment: The dump contains only your data, no system tables, so original users are not restored - and some stored program (procedure, trigger etc.) has a definer which does not exist on the target server - create user `'lipl_ga_app'@'%'` and grant it proper permissions.

Comment: how can we take hot backup of MySQL users @Nawaz Sohail can you let me know how can we split files and combine the backup.

Comment: Now either remove the lines till which backup is restored or do as suggested to split backup to multiple files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve this in many ways but, didn't find any workaround. then I tried to redo the whole thing again with the below steps.

I took a backup of mysql user from Master Host,

> mysqldump -u root -p mysql user > user_table_dump.sql

and restored mysql user on slave,

> mysql -u root -p mysql < user_table_dump.sql

then I restored the master dump on slave.

> [root@Slave ~]$ mysql -u root -p < dump.sql

The master dump restored without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is an old question, but still came up top in Google search.
I was facing this *exact* same issue before, and the looks like previous answer by Mongrel works.
However, when I reinstalled my computer, I have made a dump using `mysqldump --all-databases`, and this error 1449 inadvertently came up, and extracting `mysql` database only from the formatted drive is almost certainly impossible.

So, I finally came up with a "manual" solution by editing the `.sql` dump:
*Move the restore statements of `mysql` database up top.*
Now on very long dumps (GBs size) this is error prone.
So,

1. fire up your trusted text editor (I trust `vim` for stuffs like this, VS Code crawls like no progress opening GB size files)
2. search for **Current Database: `mysql`** comment / marker.
3. select the text from that point up to the next *Current Database:* comment/marker.
4. Cut it, put it **before** the first *Current Database* comment/marker.

Afterwards, I saved the modified dump, and now the dump restores without error.